# How to define a Sparse Fieldset in a Rails request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a simple way to implement requesting a [Sparse Fieldset](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets) in a rails JSON request?

`/some/endpoint.json?fields=id,name,favourite_colour`

Comment: Looks like the next version of [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#jsonapi) 0.10, will have better support for JSONAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I've found is to do it within a serialiser.

```
 module V2
   class BaseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
     self.root = true

     def include?(field)
       if @options.key?(:fields)
         return @options[:fields].include? field.to_s
       end
       super field
     end
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can do something like

`render json: @sth, only: params[:fields].split(',').map(&:to_sym)`

you should also wrap it in some strong params, to disallow non existing attributes

(but I doubt for it to be best possible solution)

Comment: I think that's reasonable for as the simplest solution. You should however check whether there actually are any fields present. Also you don't need to cast them into symbols, strings will do just fine. Finally, non existing attributes will be silently ignored, I'd just make sure that the user is allowed to see the requested set.

Comment: @JiříPospíšil I've checked in console without `.map(&:to_sym)` and the returned json was empty

Comment: That's weird. It works for me with just strings in both Rails 4.2.0 and 4.1.8. What version are you running?

Comment: 4.2.0 with ruby 2.2.0, here is my sample: 
`k = "vip_valid_until,email"`
`render json: license, only: k.split(',') => ["{}"]` 
`render json: license, only: k.split(',').map(&:to_sym)
=> ["{\"vip_valid_until\":\"2015-01-07T22:31:00.000+01:00\",\"email\":\"\"}"]`

Comment: Now that's interesting. I cannot find any differences :) https://gist.github.com/jiripospisil/92ef348b27f5ee6f4064

Comment: I haven't noticed any differences also when doing this directly, like in your example, although when using `.split(',')` it doesn't work, don't know why :/